# How to view perpendicular relative to the armature in 3d view?

Tags: 3d-view

I have problem viewing armature for example from the side view, because the armature is already rotated.
Is there a way to view it like using the numpad, but relative to the armature and not to the world.

Comment: maybey what you want is Shift 1, 3, 7 etc... instead of 1, 3, 7, etc... Shift will align with the selected object orientation, not the global orientation

Comment: That seems to be the answer so submit it as an answer so that other people looking for a similar problem are more likely to find this answer